# Readline autocomplete and whitespace

Tags: python, autocomplete, readline

I am using readline in python for autocompletion

I am trying to have it so if i have:

```
names = ['ben dodds', 'james asda', 'izzy smidt']
```

When I have

```
> Insert name: 
> be TAB
ben dodds
> ben TAB
ben dodds, james asda, izzy smidt
```

The last one is wrong as it should only show ben dodds

This is my code so far:

```
def completer(text, state):
    options = [x for x in names if x.startswith(text)]
    try:
        return options[state]
    except IndexError:
        return None



readline.set_completer(completer)
if 'libedit' in readline.__doc__:
    readline.parse_and_bind("bind ^I rl_complete")
else:
    readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")

name = raw_input('Enter name\n')
print name
```

So far I have gathered it is something to do with `readline.set_completer_delims()` but I cant figure out how to get it to work, any help would be appreciated

I have already tried

```
    readline.set_completer_delims('')
```

It didnt work

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
readline.set_completer_delims('')
```

I added that line to your script as follows:

```
import readline


names = ['ben dodds', 'james asda', 'izzy smidt']

def completer(text, state):
    options = [x for x in names if x.startswith(text)]
    try:
        return options[state]
    except IndexError:
        return None


readline.set_completer(completer)
readline.set_completer_delims('')

if 'libedit' in readline.__doc__:
    readline.parse_and_bind("bind ^I rl_complete")
else:
    readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")

name = raw_input('Enter name\n')
print name
```

That fixed the issue for me (using python 2.7.3 or 2.7.6 on 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04).

Comment: are you sure you are typing ben SPACE TAB? not just ben TAB

Comment: Yup.  When I type `ben<SPACE><TAB>`, it completes `ben dodds`.  If I comment out the call to `set_completer_delims`, I get the multiple choices.

Comment: I think the problem is to do with macs using libedit see http://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html any idea on how i can overcome this?